# Parsing multiple fields to the same parameter using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to parse an array of values to the same parameter in a cypher query via the REST API.

In the example taken from the neo4j documentation: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html

**A cypher query such as the following:**

```
MATCH (x { name: { startName }})-[r]-(friend)
WHERE friend.name = { name }
RETURN TYPE(r)
```

**Cypher query via the REST API using the JSON format will look something like this.**

```
{
  "query" : "MATCH (x {name: {startName}})-[r]-(friend) WHERE friend.name = {name} RETURN TYPE(r)",
  "params" : {
     "startName" : "I",
     "name" : "you"
  }
}
```

But what if I want to place multiple values for say example startName in addition to "I", perhaps "HIM" "HER" etc? Tried with the following but it didnt work. I would think making multiple such queries to complete all startName values will take a long time if lets say I've got thousands of values to go through

```
{
  "query" : "MATCH (x {name: {startName}})-[r]-(friend) WHERE friend.name = {name} RETURN TYPE(r)",
  "params" : {
     "startName" : "I","HER","HIM"
     "name" : "you"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `"startName" : ["I","HER","HIM"],` ?